# Equation $\ \binom xn'\ =\ \log(n)$

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis

**Problem:**   Solve equation

$$ \binom xn'\ =\ \log(n) $$

Here prime stands for the derivative with respect to $x$.

> Observe that:

$\quad$ for integer $n$ large,
the ***approximate*** solution is $\ x=n\ $
(it's extra off by Euler's $\gamma$).

Comment: Not for this forum.  Besides, the right hand side does not involve x, meaning the left hand side is linear in x, so n must be one. (Except that doesn't' work either.) Gerhard "One For A Different Forum" Paseman, 2017.06.23.

Comment: The OP wants to consider, for each positive integer $n$, ${x \choose n}$ as a polynomial  $f_n(x)$ of degree $n$, and solve $f_n'(x) = \log(n)$ (where $x$ is near $n$).  Of course a closed-form solution is out of the question, but asymptotic solutions are possible.

Comment: I hope the OP will at least rewrite the question so it is not subject to the same misinterpretation that misled both @GerhardPaseman and me.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, only the classical arithmetic form is "out of question". But there is plenty of potential opportunities for other neat closed form answers.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg, you're dreaming if you think that you and Gerhard are subjected to the same illusions. Anyway, seriously, could you say more about the "misinterpretation" (if it still matters).

Comment: @WlodAA:  Like Gerhard, I thought that you were seeking an $n$ that would make the equation true for all $x$, not for an $x$ that would make the equation true for a given $n$.  I'd have avoided this  misinterpretation if I'd realized who you were (in which case I'd have realized you were unlikely to ask anything quite so crazy), but I might also have avoided it if I'd stopped to think for a moment.  I apologize for not taking that moment, and I am retracting my close vote.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg, thank you, so nice! (There was no unknown function symbol like "f(x)" hence there was no differential equation, if that was the diversion).

Comment: Anthony Quas, Steven Landsburg, Mark Sapir, René, Stefan Kohl -- can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

Surely you don't expect a closed-form formula for a root of a polynomial of degree $n-1$.  Approximations are all you can hope for.

If $f_n(x) = {x \choose n}$ and $H_{n,m} = \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k^m$ the generalized harmonic numbers, we have

$$ \eqalign{f_n(n) &= 1\cr
            f_n'(n) &= H_{n,1} \sim \ln(n) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} + O(1/n^2)\cr
            f_n''(n) &= H_{n,1}^2 - H_{n,2} \sim (\ln(n)+\gamma)^2 - \frac{\pi^2}{6} +  \frac{\ln(n)+1+\gamma}{n} + O(\ln(n)/n^2)\cr
}$$
and thus the next approximation after $x=n$ might be 
$$x = n - \frac{\gamma}{(\ln(n)+\gamma)^2 - \pi^2/6}$$

Comment: "Surely you don't expect a closed-form formula for a root of a polynomial of degree n−1n−1. Approximations are all you can hope for."
*** *** *** 
Not true. A meaningful, closed form answer does not have to be in classical terms of the $4$ arithmetic operations plus roots $x^{\frac 1k}$.

Comment: (I've up-voted you anyway :-) ).